# Cannot resolve method saveLatestEventInfo()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i was learning notifications in android and i had to run this example, but android studio waranted me of an error : the method "saveLatestEventInfo()" is not acceptable and also the constructor of the class Notification is crossed. HELP MEPLEASE!!!

i checked all the subject with this method but i didn't find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int ID_NOTIFICATION = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launch);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // L'icône sera une petite loupe
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_action_search;
            // Le premier titre affiché
            CharSequence tickerText = "Titre de la notification";
            // Daté de maintenant
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // La notification est créée
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, "Titre", "Texte", contentIntent);

            // Récupération du Notification Manager
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            manager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: the method "saveLatestEventInfo()" is not acceptable and also the constructor of the class Notification is crossed ... What do you mean by that?

Comment: Android studio colored in red the method to say it's an error and the constructor is deprecated. I will take screenshots of it

Comment: what actual error message do you get? Do you know what it means if a constructor or a method is marked as deprecated?

Comment: The error message is "Cannot resolve method setLatestEventInfo()". And I would love to know what's deprecated

Comment: that error message means that that method does not exist (at least for that class). You may be calling it on an instance of the wrong class, or you mistyped the name, or you forgot the parameter(s).

Comment: deprecated means that it shouldn't be used (anymore). It used to be a good method/constructor, but now it has been replaced by a better one, and you should use that.The only reason the deprecated constructor is still there, is to give people who have used in their projects time to update their code so the code doesn't immediately crash. But it might be deleted in a future version, it's also no longer maintained.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late answers, I'm a little bit sick.